# Flask upload cannot find directory in server

Tags: python, flask

I have problem with Flask upload in local machine code are working but when upload code to server using apache show error

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   u'app/static/avatars/KHUON.S.png'

Code :

```
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS                  =   set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']         =   'app/static/avatars'
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH']    =   1 * 600 * 600

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/User/Profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_profile():

    if request.method == 'POST':

        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)

            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

        else:

            flash("File extension not allow.")
            return redirect(url_for('upload_profile', upload='error'))

    return render_template("profile.html")
```

Comment: Two questions:  why are you not using an actual environment variable for that, and does the path actually exist on the server (as in, is there anything in that `app/static/avatars` folder)?

Comment: Third question. What is the return value of `os.getcwd()` inside `upload_profile()`?

Comment: @Makoto - Path actually exist on the server /var/www/music/app/static/avatars. I don't know how to use actual environment.

Comment: @Robᵩ I don't understand about your question.

Comment: Can you add `print (os.getcwd())` as the first line of `upload_profile()` and report what it prints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, in upload.py you could do something like

```
import os
absolute_path = os.path.abspath(UPLOAD_FOLDER+file_name)
```

os.path.abspath returns the absolute path from the given relative path.